# PHP => ORM vs Stored Procedures for high concurrencies?

Tags: php

we are building a system that will have very high concurrencies.

For optimization sake, we are thinking about only using Stored Procedures, instead of simplifying our life with an ORM.

Is it a good thing to do?

Is there any ORM out there that are really worth it performance wise, with a very low footprint?

Comment: Before optimizing the database interaction examine the possibility to avoid hitting the database. Like, should every request fetch live data from the db or can you cache results? Can you generate commonly used data on scheduled time intervals? Can you store and serve data directly in the format the client can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a general answer.

An ORM can be as simple as a few lines of code or as complex as the monstrosity that is Doctrine.

Performance wise, I'm not sure you'll see much difference between using stored procedures and an ORM whose back-end uses prepared statements. It's probably worth benchmarking to find out.

However, from a maintainability point of view, Take, for example, the addition of a field in a table. In an ORM this could be as simple as a single file edit. With stored procedures it can mean updating a lot of stored procedures to account for it.

An ORM gives more flexibility as it doesn't tie all your data to the database and gives you more portability moving forwards. Of course it's weighing these benefits to whether you think they're worthwhile.

That said, there's nothing to stop an ORM calling stored procedures either.